# Work-around for arraylist being final so that items can be added to it

Tags: java, interface, final

I am trying to add `Clothing` objects to an arraylist from an overridden method in another class, which forces it to be declared final. However, when a variable is declared final it cannot be changed, yet this is exactly what I need to do. Here is the code:

```
final List<Clothing> clothingItems = new ArrayList<>();
mClothingRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
        Clothing clothing = snapshot.getValue(Clothing.class);
        clothingItems.add(clothing);
    }
}
```

How can I get around the fact that `clothingItems` is final, so that the `clothingItems` list is populated with the `Clothing` objects?

Comment: You can still add items, you just can't reassign the variable to another list.

Comment: Nothing stops you adding items to it.

Comment: When I run this code the list remains unchanged, nothing is being added even though it should. I assumed this was because it was final.

Comment: It does not matter,it will be added, just dont re-assign a new ArrayList into your clothingItems  variable

Comment: Why do you say "the list remains unchanged"? Could you provide the code that asserts that?

Comment: The only way that allows to remove the final modifier is declaring `clothingItems` as instance variable.

Comment: When I add `Log.d(TAG, clothingItems.toString());` below this block of code the logged list is `[]` which means it is empty, I have already checked that the objects being added to the list are not null.

Comment: Probably is not calling `onChildAdded` method.  Put some traces or breakpoints.

Comment: No the onChildAdded method is being called.

Comment: Do you add the logging after the `onChildAdded` Block? You'll have to add it after `clothingItems.add`, since the adding won't have happened before that listener has been called.

Comment: Yes I add it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

`final` isn't your problem here - you can add elements to a final list:

```
final List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray())); // Prints []
items.add(1);
items.add(2);
items.add(3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray())); // Prints [1,2,3]
```

What you can't do (which is blocked at compile time) is reassign the `items` variable to anything else:

```
final List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray()));
items.add(1);
items.add(2);
items.add(3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items.toArray()));
items = new ArrayList<>(); //Compile error here
```

If it looks like it's not being populated, then there's another issue here - it's nothing to do with the fact it's final. In any case, if you do have issues with things being final, you'll get compile errors rather than exceptions thrown at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `clothingItems.size()` below will give a different answer depending on whether your anonymous class ChildEventListener is triggered or not.

```
final List<Clothing> clothingItems = new ArrayList<>();
mClothingRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String s) {
        Clothing clothing = snapshot.getValue(Clothing.class);
        clothingItems.add(clothing);
    }
}

// if addChildEvent is triggered then clothingItems will be updated otherwise it will still have the same value

System.out.println(clothingItems.size());
```